# How can I pass data to a chart and make the chart adapt dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

how can I pass data to a chart and make the chart adapt dynamically? This is my code now (like the documentation, I use vue-google-chars)

```
import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue';
import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts';

export const type = 'PieChart';

export const data = [
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', 7],
];

export const options = {
  title: 'My Daily Activities',
  width: 450,
  height: 250,
};

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'GoogleChart',
  components: {
    GChart,
  },
  setup() {
    return () =>
      h(GChart, {
        data,
        options,
        type,
      });
  },
});
```

And this is how I put the label in my .vue file

```
<PieChart />
```

How can I pass data so that the chart takes it and displays it automatically, allowing me to reuse this component? (chart-data only, chart-options will be the same for all charts)

Comment: You would have a method on the component that accepts new data and tells the internal chart to refresh.

Comment: If you update `data`, it should just work.  https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts#usage  "A chart will be redrawn automatically once `data`, `type` and `options` prop is changed."

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to make the chart's code expect the data arguments

Comment: I have this, but I have to modify the chart file to accept the data that I send `<PieChart :chart-data="chartData" />`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass data as [props](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#declaring-render-functions) to your reusable GChart component.

You can set a default value for your prop. Below I set the default value for a prop called `chartData` using your original `export const data` value.  The last step is passing in `props` to the `setup()` function and setting the GChart `data` equal to `props.chartData`

```js
import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue';
import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts';

export const type = 'PieChart';

export const options = {
  title: 'My Daily Activities',
  width: 450,
  height: 250,
};

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'GoogleChart',
  components: {
    GChart
  },
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2],
        ['Commute', 2],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
      ]
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    return () =>
      h(GChart, {
        data: props.chartData,
        options,
        type
      })
  }
})
```

Now elsewhere in your app you can import your component as PieChart and `chartData` can be set as needed and will reactively update your chart when changed.

```html
<PieChart :chart-data="chartData" />
```

Example script code where chartData is updated with a button click:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <PieChart :chart-data="chartData" />
    <button @click="update">update data</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PieChart from "./components/GChart.js";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { PieChart },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: undefined, // use default chart data initially
      usersCount: 1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.chartData = [
        ["Task", "Hours per Day"],
        ["type one", this.usersCount],
      ];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[Example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sid-rzvjfn?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I tried that, and doesnt work. When I set the chartData, the code is ok but I don't see the chart in my page. This is how I set the chartData
`return {usersCount: 0,chartData: [['type one', this.usersCount],],};`

Comment: chartData needs to be an array of at least 2 arrays.  Even though it's not really used in a pie chart, the first array represents the "column" names, e.g. `['Task', 'Hours per Day']` shown in the default data.  If your first and only "row" array data value (usersCount) is 0, then the chart will also not display because the only data point is 0 which can not be displayed on a pie chart.  I've updated my answer with even more detail.

Comment: okey, I understand, but I need the chart updates for himself

Comment: How do you mean? `<PieChart>` will update any and every time `chartData` changes, provided the data is valid for the chart.